# Sentry self hosted problems

Tags: node.js, sentry, self-hosting

Hi guys I'm working with sentry at some time and everything goes fine. But now the server it's going to be self hosted sentry. My question is the server is old and some times go down, get stuck and need to restart.

Does it will impact the projects? I know that when the service goes down the issues will not be stored, but does it impact the project in some way?

I look in  [self hosted section](https://develop.sentry.dev/self-hosted/) of sentry and didn't found any info about this. Is there some configuration to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer your question in parts.

1. **Does the sentry server going down affect the projects** - sentry is a monitoring tool, doesn't affect the project's operation directly, only that the events received during this downtime will never be received or stored, it will just be lost.
2. **Is there any configuration to prevent the server from going down** - this is not Sentry's error that your old server is going down by itself. You must take a look at resources allocated for the server and adjust accordingly.

When you self-host Sentry, its operation and uptime is completely in your hands.